# How to configure apache in local development in rails

Tags: linux, apache, host

I am trying setup a loacl domain on my pc for that I have apache server install I want to open my rails s inside this abcd.com instead of 127.0.0.1:3000. In my host I have changed host file like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   abcd.com
```

But when I am trying to open abcd.com with this command I am getting this message:

```
 Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 80 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

When I stop apache it works on localhost any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to write all hostnames behind the ip like this :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost abcd.com
```